# Change HTML form 'input' type by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, input

How can I do this through the tag itself?

Change type from text to password

```
<input type='text' name='pass' />
```

Is it possible to insert JavaScript code inside the *[input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text)* tag itself to change type='text' to type='password'?

Answer (score 63):

Try:

```html
<input id="hybrid" type="text" name="password" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('hybrid').type = 'password';
</script>
```

Comment: This assumes that your input looks like this `<input id="myElement" type="text"/>` so remember to assign an ID to it

Comment: How could it be done inside the <input> tag itself without using script

Comment: By using any one of the events an input field can have - onfocus, onclick etc, and placing in something like `this.type='password'`.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can even change it by triggering an event

```
<input type='text' name='pass'  onclick="(this.type='password')" />


<input type="text" placeholder="date" onfocusin="(this.type='date')" onfocusout="(this.type='text')">
```

Comment: great help.keep it up

Comment: This has a bug. When you need to focus using `Shift+Tab` it triggers `onfocusin` and `onfocusout` at the same time, making it not to focus on the input

Answer (score 13):

Changing the `type` of an `<input type=password>` throws a security error in some browsers (old IE and Firefox versions).

You’ll need to create a new `input` element, set its `type` to the one you want, and clone all other properties from the existing one.

I do this in my jQuery placeholder plugin: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder/blob/master/jquery.placeholder.js#L80-84

To work in Internet Explorer:

- dynamically create a new element
- copy the properties of the old element into the new element
- set the type of the new element to the new type
- replace the old element with the new element

The function below accomplishes the above tasks for you:

```
<script>
function changeInputType(oldObject, oType) {
    var newObject = document.createElement('input');
    newObject.type = oType;
    if(oldObject.size) newObject.size = oldObject.size;
    if(oldObject.value) newObject.value = oldObject.value;
    if(oldObject.name) newObject.name = oldObject.name;
    if(oldObject.id) newObject.id = oldObject.id;
    if(oldObject.className) newObject.className = oldObject.className;
    oldObject.parentNode.replaceChild(newObject,oldObject);
    return newObject;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Would this work without using all the if conditions?  I am having the same issue, but I don't need the objects to equal each other.

Comment: @JPHochbaum Sure. In fact, my original answer didn’t contain all that extra code — someone else added it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I have for mine.

Essentially you are utilizing the *onfocus* and *onblur* commands in the <input> tag to trigger the appropriate JavaScript code.  It could be as simple as:

```
<span><input name="login_text_password" type="text" value="Password" onfocus="this.select(); this.setAttribute('type','password');" onblur="this.select(); this.setAttribute('type','text');" /></span>
```

An evolved version of this basic functionality checks for and empty string and returns the password input back to the original "Password" in the event of a null textbox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function password_set_attribute() {
        if (document.getElementsByName("login_text_password")[0].value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ') == "" ||
            document.getElementsByName[0].value == null) {

            document.getElementsByName("login_text_password")[0].setAttribute('type','text')
            document.getElementsByName("login_text_password")[0].value = 'Password';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementsByName("login_text_password")[0].setAttribute('type','password')
        }
    }
</script>
```

Where HTML looks like:

```
<span><input name="login_text_password" class="roundCorners" type="text" value="Password" onfocus="this.select(); this.setAttribute('type','password');" onblur="password_set_attribute();" /></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to add a '.value' to the end of [Evert's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093992/change-html-form-input-type-by-javascript/9094198#9094198) to get it working.

Also I combined it with a browser check so that the ***input*** *type="number"* field is changed to *type="text"* in Chrome since 'formnovalidate' doesn't seem to work right now.

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1)
    document.getElementById("input_id").attributes["type"].value = "text";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by some browsers (Internet Explorer if I recall), but it works in the rest:

```
document.getElementById("password-field").attributes["type"] = "password";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("password-field").attributes["type"] = "text";
```

Comment: What version of Internet Explorer? [Internet Explorer 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_6)?

Answer (score 1):

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
let input = document.querySelector('#username');

btn.addEventListener('click',()=> {
    if ( input.type === "password") {
        input.type = "text"
    } else {
        input.type = "password"


    }
})
```

```html
<input type="password" id="username" >

<button id="btn">change Attr</button>
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70255395/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple toggle with [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery). It works also with the the [ASP.NET MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC) EditorFor() when you have a DataType.Password on the model property.

```
    function showPassword() {
        let password = $(".password");

        if (password[0].type == "password") {
            password[0].type = "";
        }
        else {
            password[0].type = "password";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".show-pass").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var type = $("#signupform-password").attr('type');
    switch (type) {
        case 'password':
        {
            $("#signupform-password").attr('type', 'text');
            return;
        }
        case 'text':
        {
            $("#signupform-password").attr('type', 'password');
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="password" class="show-pass">
```

Comment: This doesn't show how to change a type using vanilla Javscript, it's a jQuery approach. That's becoming less and less relevant since jQuery isn't used much for new projects.

Comment: @moopet yet three and a half years after you made this comment, polls show 25% of developers are still using it.

Comment: @Mattt it's still not relevant to the question, and a low-quality code-only answer. The issue has morphed from popularity to the fact that it's now _more_ effort, and slower, to do it the jQuery way than the vanilla JS way.

Comment: @moopet... I don't disagree with the rest of your assessment of this answer. I just suggested that jquery is still used a lot. Even for new projects. Your other points are completely valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
const myTimeout = setTimeout(show, 5000);

function show() {
  document.getElementById('pass').type = "text";
}

clearTimeout(myTimeout);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //html
 <input type="password" id="password_input">
 <i onclick="passwordDisplay()" class="ti-eye"></i>

 //js
 const input = document.getElementById("password_input")

 function passwordDisplay() { 
    if (input.attributes["type"].value == "text")
        input.attributes["type"].value = "password"
     else
        input.attributes["type"].value = "text"
    
 }
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answer, and add some explanation. Especially when answering to old questions, it is important to explain why your answer is different, and even better than existing answers. See [answers].

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JavaScript setAttribute method
`elementName.setAttribute('class') = 'value';`

Comment: The setAttribute method works a little bit different as mentioned. you have to set attrbute-name and value in the method parameters like `setAttribute(name, value)`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Answer (score -2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.or/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function changefield(){
    document.getElementById("passwordbox").innerHTML = "<input id=\"passwordfield\" type=\"password\" name=\"password-field\" title=\"Password\" tabindex=\"2\" />";
    document.getElementById("password-field".focus();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="passwordbox">
<input id="password-field" type="text" name="password-field" title="Password"onfocus="changefield();" value="Password" tabindex="2" />
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="sign in" tabindex="3" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. Please respond by [editing (changing) your question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9094107/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: I second Peter...