# IE[10-11]: input element's value becomes equals placeholder text

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, placeholder, hidden-field

I've found the following problem. Imagine that we have input[type="text"] element without value and with some placehplder text. When input's type is dynamically changed  from "text" to "hidden" input's value becomes equals placeholder text. The issue doesn't occur for "static" hidden inputs.

The following code and a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qoqvory8/9) demonstrate the problem:

```
<input type="text" name="oprDate" placeholder="Date" class="form-control field-oprDate-control" value="">
<button id="btn" type="button">Run</button>
<div>
  Input's value is is: 
  <span id="res"></span>
</div>

var btn = document.getElementById("btn"),
    input = document.getElementsByName("oprDate")[0],
    res = document.getElementById("res");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    input.type = "hidden";
    res.innerHTML = input.value;
});
```

I suppose that such behavior is incorrect even if placeholder attribute is useless for hidden inputs. What do you think?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093992/change-html-input-type-by-js

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Comment: Funny behavior. But if your issue is that the placeholder is getting submitted you can make input "disabled" and hidden. That will stop client from submitting the value. Just a workaround.

Comment: @Rohan210 I use IE 10 and 11