# On-clicking on image is not working

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I tried doing this, there's an image and an input field. The input field is kept hidden. When I click on the image, the input field will change from hidden to text.

The code I tried is below:

```js
function inp()
{
  var y=document.getElementByID("hiddenInput");
  y.type= "text";
}
```

```html
HTML:
    
<img src="lc.png" height="120px" onclick="inp()" />

<div><input type="hidden" id="hiddenInput" placeholder="What are you looking 
    for?"></div>
```

Things are not working. The image is not on-clickable, and nothing happens when we click. I would be glad if anyone can tell me please where the problem is?

There are another questions on stack overflow asking how to make an image on-clickable, I tried the code, and it went wrong, so I asked where the mistake is.. Now I got the answer. It is a silly mistake, but I think it's okay since I am new here.. Thanks to those who helped me. My problem is solved now :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change html input type by JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093992/change-html-input-type-by-js)

Comment: change from getElementByID to getElementById. Solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change **getElementByID** to **getElementById** . The different is at the 'ID' part

Answer (score 1):

`var y=document.getElementByID("hiddenInput");` change it to

```
var y=document.getElementById("hiddenInput");
```

**DEMO:**

```js
function inp(){
  console.log("done");
  var y=document.getElementById("hiddenInput");
                y.type= "text";
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_paris.jpg" height="120px" onclick="inp()" />

<div><input type="hidden" id="hiddenInput" placeholder="What are you looking 
for?"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure your `script` tag is above `img` tag

And  change `getElementByID` to `getElementById`

```
<script>
function inp()
            {
                var y=document.getElementById("hiddenInput");
                y.type= "text";
            }
</script>

<img src="lc.png" height="120px" onclick="inp()" />

<div><input type="hidden" id="hiddenInput" placeholder="What are you looking 
for?"></div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xya0tq8t/2/

Or

If you are using separate JS file then make sure js code runs after DOM is ready

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <img src="lc.png" height="120px" onclick="inp()" />

    <div><input type="hidden" id="hiddenInput" placeholder="What are you looking 
    for?"></div>

<script>
  function inp() {
    document.getElementById("hiddenInput").setAttribute('type','text'); 
  }
</script>                
</body>
</html>
```