# How to select type attribute of input tag based on a javascript variable as condition ?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a input tag to get text input from client side

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Message" id="messageText"  autofocus/>
```

Now I want to select the type attribute based on a javascript variable **password_flag**

If `password_flag==1` then `type="password"` else `type="text"`

So, when password_flag will be set user will be able to give password input

As I have been using uwsgi as server, I can't use FreeMarker to invoke conditions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change html input type by JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093992/change-html-input-type-by-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with vanilla javascript as well:

```js
var password_flag = 1;
  
var input = document.getElementById('messageText');
  
if(password_flag === 1){
 input.setAttribute('type','password');
} else{
  input.setAttribute('type','text');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Message" id="messageText"  autofocus/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this easily by the `if-else` condition:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var password_flag = 1; 
  if(password_flag === 1){
    $('#messageText').attr('type', 'password');
  } else {
    $('#messageText').attr('type', 'text');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Message" id="messageText"  autofocus/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even achieve it by using event inline

```js
var password_flag = 1;
//var password_flag = 0;
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Message" id="messageText"   onclick="password_flag?this.type='password':this.type='text'" autofocus />
```